# How can I use a button to get a touch input and output the location to a label in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, touch

I've just started playing with Swift, so apologies if this is a stupid question.
I'm trying to create a button so that when the user presses it and then touches the screen inside an image it will save the location of the touch as a CGPoint and change the text on a label to the coordinates.

So far I've got the below, but I'm not sure what arguments should be used to call the `touchesBegan` function from the `IBAction` of the button, or if I'm completely going about this the wrong way.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    // *********** Set Coordinates ****************
    // variable to be set as the location of the user's touch
    var toploc:CGPoint? = nil

    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

    // label that will change to the coordinates of the touch
    @IBOutlet weak var Topcoord: UILabel!

    func touchesBegan(_ touches:Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) -> CGPoint {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let position = touch.location(in: myImageView)
            return position
        } else {
            // print("in else")
        }
    }

    // button that stores location of user's touch and displays the coordinates in the Topcoord text

    @IBAction func settop(_ sender: Any) {
        toploc = touchesBegan(Set<UITouch>, UIEvent)
        Topcoord.text = String(describing: toploc)
    }

    // ************** default stuff ***************
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `touchesBegan` function from your code, because UIKit calls this method. When this method fired, just save the last location in your `toploc` variable and then use it in `settop` function when user will press the button. E.g.

```
var toploc: CGPoint?

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first

    if let position = touch?.location(in: myImageView) {
        toploc = position  // 
    }
}

@IBAction func settop(_ sender: Any)
{
    topCoord.text = String(describing: toploc)
}
```

Сamel style is commonly used in Swift for names, first symbol in uppercase for types (and protocols) and lowercase for everything else. So, your code will look better if `Topcoord` variable name will change to 'topCoord' or 'topCoordinates'.

Comment: That's massive help. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to use a `UITapGestureRecognizer`, which will actually give you the location of the touch. You can add it to your image view either in the storyboard/XIB or programmatically. E.g.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTapped(_:)))
    myImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}

@IBAction func viewTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.state {
    case .ended:
        Topcoord.text = "\(sender.location(ofTouch: 0, in: view))"
    case .possible, .began, .changed, .cancelled, .failed:
        break
    }
}
```

P.S. You never create `UITouch` objects, they're created privately within `UIKit`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I've got it working with the first suggestion, but this looks like an interesting way to do it. I'll have a go with doing it this way as well. Thanks again.